How to return multiple table rows ( same row ) but with different include/joined table record each?
I have a conversation (table) that has many messages (table),
When I run:
            let results = await conversation.findAll({
                include: [
                    {
                        required: true,
                        model: Message,
                        as: 'messages',
                        where: message_query,
                        // seperate: true,
                        // limit: 1
                    },
                ]
            })
                .then(data => {

                    return data;

            })


I get something like:
[
   { // Conversation
      "id":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "phone_number_id":1,
      "contact_id":3,
      "status":"open",
      "chatbot_status":"enabled",
      "blocked":false,
      "last_active":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "start_at":null,
      "end_at":"2024-03-29T08:16:10.000Z",
      "expiry_date":1714121760,
      "created_at":"2023-08-25T06:10:06.000Z",
      "updated_at":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "unreadCount":0,
      "messages":[ 
         { // Message: 1383
            "id":1383,
            "conversation_id":1,
            "user_id":1,
            "reply_message_id":null,
            "reaction_message_id":null,
            "parameters":"{\"type\":\"text\",\"header\":null,\"body\":\"123\",\"footer\":null,\"buttons\":null}",
            "keywords":"123",
            "type":"send",
            "status":"sent",
            "error_code":null,
            "error_message":null,
            "created_at":"2024-06-14T11:29:57.000Z",
            "updated_at":"2024-06-14T11:29:57.000Z"
         },
         { // Message: 1371
            "id":1371,
            "conversation_id":1,
            "user_id":1,
            "reply_message_id":null,
            "reaction_message_id":null,
            "parameters":"{\"type\":\"text\",\"header\":null,\"body\":\"123\",\"footer\":null,\"buttons\":null}",
            "keywords":"123",
            "type":"send",
            "status":"sent",
            "error_code":null,
            "error_message":null,
            "created_at":"2024-06-14T10:07:59.000Z",
            "updated_at":"2024-06-14T10:07:59.000Z"
         },
         { // Message: ...
            ......
         }
      ]
   }
]

But what I actually want from Sequelize is:
[
   { // Conversation : same
      "id":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "phone_number_id":1,
      "contact_id":3,
      "status":"open",
      "chatbot_status":"enabled",
      "blocked":false,
      "last_active":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "start_at":null,
      "end_at":"2024-03-29T08:16:10.000Z",
      "expiry_date":1714121760,
      "created_at":"2023-08-25T06:10:06.000Z",
      "updated_at":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "unreadCount":0,
      "messages":[ 
         { // Message: 1383
            "id":1383,
            "conversation_id":1,
            "user_id":1,
            "reply_message_id":null,
            "reaction_message_id":null,
            "parameters":"{\"type\":\"text\",\"header\":null,\"body\":\"123\",\"footer\":null,\"buttons\":null}",
            "keywords":"123",
            "type":"send",
            "status":"sent",
            "error_code":null,
            "error_message":null,
            "created_at":"2024-06-14T11:29:57.000Z",
            "updated_at":"2024-06-14T11:29:57.000Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   
   { // Conversation : same
      "id":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "phone_number_id":1,
      "contact_id":3,
      "status":"open",
      "chatbot_status":"enabled",
      "blocked":false,
      "last_active":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "start_at":null,
      "end_at":"2024-03-29T08:16:10.000Z",
      "expiry_date":1714121760,
      "created_at":"2023-08-25T06:10:06.000Z",
      "updated_at":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "unreadCount":0,
      "messages":[ 
         { // Message: 1371
            "id":1371,
            "conversation_id":1,
            "user_id":1,
            "reply_message_id":null,
            "reaction_message_id":null,
            "parameters":"{\"type\":\"text\",\"header\":null,\"body\":\"123\",\"footer\":null,\"buttons\":null}",
            "keywords":"123",
            "type":"send",
            "status":"sent",
            "error_code":null,
            "error_message":null,
            "created_at":"2024-06-14T10:07:59.000Z",
            "updated_at":"2024-06-14T10:07:59.000Z"
         },
         {
            ......
         }
      ]
   },
   
   { // Conversation : same
      "id":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "phone_number_id":1,
      "contact_id":3,
      "status":"open",
      "chatbot_status":"enabled",
      "blocked":false,
      "last_active":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "start_at":null,
      "end_at":"2024-03-29T08:16:10.000Z",
      "expiry_date":1714121760,
      "created_at":"2023-08-25T06:10:06.000Z",
      "updated_at":"2024-06-18T02:46:50.000Z",
      "unreadCount":0,
      "messages":[ 
         { // Message: ...
            ......
         }
      ]
   }
   
]

Is this achievable without using raw query?
If I use raw SQL it returns multiple rows unlike Sequelize

Add the option raw: true and nested: true?
